# RecyclerView Kotlin, unable to add recycler widget to layout

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to implement RecyclerView in Kotlin. Following guides but getting an error right after launch "My Application keeps stopping"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Basically I just added Recycler widget to my layout. Nothing else changed from template empty activity starter project.

Comment: Have you inflated the recyclerview? Then add that code also. And as you are using `androidx` constraintlayout, you have to use androidx components everywhere, not support components.

Comment: no other changes to the project except mentioned above and adding library to gradle

Comment: use androidx library if still not working post activity/fragment code

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be you are not using `androidx` version of `RecyclerView`

Dependency if not added already:

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

then replace your code with:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Also in your Activity/fragment make sure your are using

```
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Common mistake is not adding `app:layoutManager` to your `RecyclerView` in your XML layout:

```
app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
```

Comment: That didnt really change anything

Comment: there's no other changes to starter project than code in my question, I dont thing logs are needed here

Comment: ok I think you forgot some views in `onCreate()`. It's most probably a null pointer exception then. Cause you might be trying to set something on a view that doesn't exist. I can't think of any other reason.

Comment: Actually makes sense to check logs i'm getting this error: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication1, PID: 4764
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication1/com.example.myapplication1.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

Comment: I didnt really change anything mainactivity.kt

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem, it was a mismatch on layout, recycler view needed more properties to match main layout:

```
   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myFirstRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```